# How can I find unassigned (but assignable) IP addresses for testing purposes?

Tags: testing, ip-address, asp.net-web-api

I'm testing various free / public web APIs which take IP numbers as parameters.

I want to see what kind of results they return under various error conditions.

How can I find a regular IP address which is not yet used / assigned / sold?

I know there are some special **reserved** IP ranges which can never be assigned but I want to test specifically for the case of IP addresses **in the assignable space** because some of these web APIs may have different code to handle these cases and return different forms of results.

---

**Example:**

`freegeoip.net` response for reserved IP [`http://freegeoip.net/json/192.168.1.2`](http://freegeoip.net/json/192.168.1.2)

```
{"city": "", "region_code": "", "region_name": "", "metrocode": "", "zipcode": "", "longitude": "0", "latitude": "0", "country_code": "RD", "ip": "192.168.1.2", "country_name": "Reserved"}
```

But what does it return for IP numbers not in its database etc?

I want a way to find IP addresses for testing any such web API, not just `freegeoip.net`.

Comment: @Michael: No I hadn't - it's not something I know anything about. Care to write up an answer or give me an example IP to test?

Comment: As far as i know all IPv4 was assigned in February 3, 2011, therefore if you wish to test an unassigned IP addresses, you have to test it with IPv6

Comment: @Michael: Actually I was a bit worried about that too but didn't know at which point the country info was associated to IPs by whoever implements the geocoding stuff. I know some IPs are still available in some places but maybe at too fine-grained a level. I do know that some of the geocoding services have not known where a couple of the IPs I've tested from were but lacked a deterministic way to test...

Comment: I'm very interested in any constructive criticism the down voter may have to offer.

Answer (score -3):

Here is an IP address which codes to "Italy" no town or region.
5.90.235.59 , , Italy
The IP address works.